# Generate all Permutations of Four Events, Three Outcomes each

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Hello I would like a list of all permutations for the following set up. I tried an online permutation generator, but I didn't quite get it working, so I'll try this forum, which has been great in the past.

- Four independent events
- Each event can produce one of three different outcomes (D,S, and T in my problem)
- Order unimportant, so DDST is the same as DDTS.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Why is DD not a repeat? How can you have four events with three possible outcomes without repeats?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my question to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three variants of `DDDD` (one for each outcome), three for `DSDS` (one missing each outcome), three for `DDST` (one with each outcome doubled) and six for `DDDS` (the only one where all three outcomes play distinct roles, hence $3!=6$ variants).

Comment: Thank you. Outside of this question, some people indicated I should have 12. However, working by hand I had 15, I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something fundamental. Many thanks.